# generate a list with 6-dimensional unique elements in python

Tags: python, numpy

I need a list with 6 unique elements, like 000001, 000002, 000003 etc. It isn't neccessary have to be in digits, it can be a string, like AAAAAA, AAAAAB, ABCDEF etc.

If I generate a list with `np.arange()` I won't have 6-dimensional elements. I only decided to use 'for' cicles like

[image]

but I think there are a lot of more convenient ways to do this.

Comment: You do not need all those `str()`s.

Comment: Please don't post code as image. I cannot copy an image to my console and execute it... Code is text and this site is made for posting text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a cartesian product of the string "ABCDEF" by itself, taken five times (in other words, the product of six identical strings). It can be calculated using `product()` function from module `itertools`. The result of the product is a list of 6-tuples of individual characters. The tuples are converted to strings with `join()`.

```
from itertools import product
symbols = "ABCDEF"
[''.join(x) for x in product(*([symbols] * len(symbols)))]
#['AAAAAA', 'AAAAAB', 'AAAAAC', 'AAAAAD', 'AAAAAE', 
# 'AAAAAF', 'AAAABA', 'AAAABB', 'AAAABC', 'AAAABD',...
# 'FFFFFA', 'FFFFFB', 'FFFFFC', 'FFFFFD', 'FFFFFE', 'FFFFFF']
```

You can change the value of `symbols` to any other combination of distinct characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `combinations_with_replacement()`:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

list(map(''.join, combinations_with_replacement('ABC', r=3)))
# ['AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'ABB', 'ABC', 'ACC', 'BBB', 'BBC', 'BCC', 'CCC']
```

If you need all possible combinations use the function `product()`:

```
from itertools import product

list(map(''.join, product('ABC', repeat=3)))
# ['AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'ABC', 'ACA', 'ACB', 'ACC', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BAC', 'BBA', 'BBB', 'BBC', 'BCA', 'BCB', 'BCC', 'CAA', 'CAB', 'CAC', 'CBA', 'CBB', 'CBC', 'CCA', 'CCB', 'CCC']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.unravel_index` to get an index array:

```
idx = np.array(np.unravel_index(np.arange(30000), 6*(6,)), order='F').T
idx
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
#        ...,
#        [3, 5, 0, 5, 1, 3],
#        [3, 5, 0, 5, 1, 4],
#        [3, 5, 0, 5, 1, 5]])
```

You can replace the indices with more or less anything you like afterwards:

```
symbols = np.fromiter('ABCDEF', 'U1')
symbols
# array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], dtype='<U1')
symbols[idx]
# array([['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
#        ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
#        ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C'],
#        ...,
#        ['D', 'F', 'A', 'F', 'B', 'D'],
#        ['D', 'F', 'A', 'F', 'B', 'E'],
#        ['D', 'F', 'A', 'F', 'B', 'F']], dtype='<U1')
```

If you need the result as a list of words:

```
final = symbols[idx].view('U6').ravel().tolist()
final[:20]
# ['AAAAAA', 'AAAAAB', 'AAAAAC', 'AAAAAD', 'AAAAAE', 'AAAAAF', 'AAAABA', 'AAAABB', 'AAAABC', 'AAAABD', 'AAAABE', 'AAAABF', 'AAAACA', 'AAAACB', 'AAAACC', 'AAAACD', 'AAAACE', 'AAAACF', 'AAAADA', 'AAAADB']
```